# While compiling an application from linux, the flutter_secure_storage package gives an error

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-dependencies, snapcraft, flutter-secure-storage

While compiling an application from linux, the flutter_secure_storage package gives an error.

[image: error Image]

Error:-

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
main.dart:1
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/130/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/flutter/130/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/flutter_secure_storage_linux/linux/CMakeLists.txt:14 (pkg_check_modules)


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried the following commands.

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

```
sudo apt install libsecret-1-dev libsecret-tools libsecret-1-0
```

Comment: Which version of libsecret do you have? It has a constaint. Also, it appears to need jsoncpp. `pkg_check_modules(LIBSECRET REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libsecret-1>=0.18.4) pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET jsoncpp)`

Comment: @RichardHeap please tell me how i can install libsecret 0.18.4 version

Comment: same way you do anything. First check what version you have. Try looking in /usr/share/doc - do you see libsecret? Mine says 0.18.5 which would presumably satisfy that criterion. Then check how to install jsoncpp for your distro.

Comment: i have libsecret-1, libsecret-1-0, libsecret-dev, libsecret-tools version of libsecret.
i am using ubuntu 22.04
i try to install libsecret-0.18.4 by 
```
sudo apt install libsecret-0.18.4
```
i get 
```

Comment: The current version on Ubuntu of libsecret-1 appears to be 0.20.x which should satisfy >=0.18.4. Have you also installed jsoncpp?

Answer (score 1):

i just found a solution to this problem what work for me is the following:
change
"pkg_check_modules(LIBSECRET REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libsecret>=0.18.4)"
to
"pkg_check_modules(LIBSECRET REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libsecret-1>=0.18.4)"
in
"your_app/linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlink/flutter_secure_storage_linux/linux/CMakeLists.txt"

u can also install jsoncpp-dev

then run
$flutter clean
$flutter run -d linux

Comment: how i can install jsoncpp-dev in ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: on ubuntu i think it's $ sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev